# Does Amazon transcribe support Real Time transcription with word level time stamps?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-transcribe

I've been searching for if Amazon real time transcription does support word-level timestamps, and the closest thing I found was that AWS Transcribe Medical did support it. Do any here know if AWS does support this? If so, can you send me link with this description and/or how to begin with it?

Answer (score 0):

AWS transcribe streaming also support word level timestamp. It's not mentioned in document though. Sample transcript can be found at bottom of: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/transcribe/latest/dg/streaming.html